# Populating values in newly added column for existing files

Tags: 2013, column

I have created a new yes/no column in a document library and I need to now go through the **existing** documents (added before the new column was put in) and mark some of them as 'Yes'.  However, the edit properties function only displays the new checkbox on files created since the column was created.

How do I populate the properties on those files that were created **before** the new column was created?  Probably simple but I can't spot it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the column exists on the view, and choose Library tab, from the ribbon, then choose Quick Edit.

[image]

This will put your view in quick edit mode so you can edit it as you do with Excel.

Another way I would go for is to use PowerShell, as the previous way will only edit items in the same view, if you have paging and more items, you will need to go to that page and do the same.

Comment: That looks good, thanks. It'll speed up my back fill. Also discovered that I needed to add the new column to all the content types.

Comment: `Quick Edit` is nice and easy way but we have to keep in mind that `Modified` & `Modified By` fields value will be updated for all the documents.